# Angular 2 - No provider for Jsonp

Tags: angular

getting error:

```
inline template:16:8 caused by: No provider for Jsonp!
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Jsonp!
```

I am importing the 'HttpModule' directly into the module that the component is a part of.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to ***import and declare JsonpModule*** as shown below,

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: duh, i should have known everything is a module now.